# Error: "Cannot set current directory" if directory name starts with tilde "~"

Tags: warning-messages, files-and-directories

On MacOS, there seems to be a bug in `FileNames[]` when a directory starts with a tilde ("~").

Does anyone else see this behavior?:

```
f = CreateFile[
  FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "d", "~a", "a.txt"}],
  CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True]

(*  "/private/.../d/~a/a.txt"  *)

d = FileNameTake[f, {1, -3}]

(* "/private/.../d" *)

FileNames[All, d, 1]

(* { "/private/.../d/~a" } *)   <--- good

FileNames[All, d, 2]

Error: General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to ~a/.    <---- bad

FileNames[All, d, Infinity]

Error: General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to ~a/.    <---- bad
```

Comment: With questions like these, you will want to mention what OS you're using.

Comment: I added it (MacOS). Thanks!

Comment: I would avoid using `~` for directory names on Linux/Unix OS's as `~` is a shortcut for the `$HOME` environment variable.  Some OS commands might choose to expand `~` when it comes across it.

Comment: @Tim -- Agreed. I'm crawling over some backup directories, and one is a backup of a linux system with user directories of the form `~foo`.

Comment: Update: WRI responded: "There is a known issue with using patterns in filenames, and it seems that this is related to the same issue."